# Writing correct SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have spent a significant amount of time on this and I still don't have it quite right.

Show title ID, title, and number of authors for all books that have more than one author. I have this but don't think it is exactly correct. Using 3 tables (titles, titleauthor and authors). Shouldn't the criteria be the au_id and the number of times it is the same? My code returns strange column of 25 for each title_id. I'd like to understand how to write the correct syntax....from the wordy question.

```
 SELECT titles.title_id, titles.title, COUNT(titleauthor.au_id) AS nbrAuthors
 FROM titles CROSS JOIN titleauthor 

 GROUP BY titles.title_id, titles.title

 HAVING COUNT(titleauthor.au_id) >1
```

Updated Code: I think this is it! Writing out pseudo code helped a lot on this one.

```
SELECT titles.title_id, titles.title, COUNT(titleauthor.au_id) AS nbrOfAuthors

FROM titles LEFT JOIN titleauthor ON titles.title_id = titleauthor.title_id
GROUP BY titles.title, titles.title_id
HAVING COUNT(titleauthor.au_id)>1;
```

Comment: `a JOIN b JOIN C ...GROUP BY...`

Comment: Do you even know why you are using a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Why are you using a cross join?  I think you need to figure out how to join titleauthor to title.

Comment: That explains why I have 25 for the number of authors in the nbrAuthors column now. Thanks, I'm going to tweak. Need to join the au_id from both tables but not sure how to make the comparison whether they are the same or multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you join multiple tables together, you need to specify in the where the overlaps should be.

For example, here I think you want to add the following:

```
WHERE titles.title_id = titleauthor.title_id
AND titleauthor.au_id = authors.au_id
```

You've probably seen the following a gazillion times but remember that the syntax is:

```
SELECT foo, etc FROM tables WHERE conditions ORDER BY/GROUP BY some_field
```

Comment: Not sure if you posted before my edits to code were made. Appears I solved this one and now finished finally for the day. What was troubling is this is one of the easier problems yet I solved the other s first. Thanks for the guide...every bit of info or education I receive here is appreciated.